# How to avoid hardcoded field names in entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How do i avoid using hardcoded table and field names in entity framework? For example:

```
  Contact contact =
        contactQuery.Include("SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderDetail")
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a way to get that info from the context or metadata? I'd love to be able say SalesOrderHeader.TableName or SalesOrderHeaderFields.SalesOrderDetails.FieldName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Entity Frameworks metadata, you need to go looking through the `MetadataWorkspace` which hangs off the `ObjectContext`.

The starting point is to get the EntityType for your base type, in your case Contact.

I have an [EF tips series](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/index-of-tips.aspx) and in [Tip 13](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/04/15/tip-13-how-to-attach-an-entity-the-easy-way.aspx) I show an extension method on `MetadataWorkspace` that gets the `EntityType` for a particular CLR Type:

```
public static EntityType GetCSpaceEntityType<T>(
        this MetadataWorkspace workspace);
```

You can use this like this:

```
var contactEntity = ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetCSpaceEntityType<Contact>();
```

Once you have this you can look at it's NavigationProperties to find the relationship's and the names you are interested in including:

i.e.

```
foreach(var np in contactEntity.NavigationProperties)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Include: {0}", np.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("... Recursively include ");
    EntityType relatedType = 
       (np.ToEndMember.TypeUsage.EdmType as RefType).ElementType;
    //TODO: go repeat the same process... i.e. look at the relatedTypes 
    // navProps too until you decide to stop.
}
```

Of course how you decide what you want to Include is up to you.
Hope this helps

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Read [Say goodbye to the hardcoded ObjectQuery(T).Include calls](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/08/06/say-goodbye-to-the-hard-coded-objectquery-t-include-calls.aspx), and you will be able to do it like the following, using lambda & linq expression trees:

```
Dim c = GetObjectContext()
Dim query = c.Vendors.Include(Function(v) v.Contact.Addresses.Single.State)
```

There is a C# samle as well.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

It's just a property name, so you can get it via reflection.

Comment: I guess, but going through reflection is very expensive.

Comment: Not really. It never changes, so you only need to do it once. Make it a class static property. It will initialize in microseconds, and you will never have to do it again.

Comment: I have a better very dynamic solution using expression trees, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683960/how-to-avoid-hardcoded-field-names-in-entity-framework/3433134#3433134

Answer (score 0):

Example (would love to hear better ideas, didn't find a way to accept a type name as a reference like the VB GetType does):

**VB:**

```
<Extension()>
Function GetRelation(Of TEntity As Type)(entity As TEntity,
 ParamArray path() As TEntity) As String
  GetRelation = entity.Name
  For Each type In path
    GetRelation &= "." & type.Name
  Next
End Function

'Here is your line:
Dim x = Context.Employee.Include(
 GetType(Contact).GetRelation(GetType(SalesOrderHeader),
 GetType(SalesOrderDetail)))
```

**C#:**

```
static string GetRelation<TEntity>(this TEntity entity, params TEntity[] path)
 where TEntity : Type
{
   string ret = entity.Name;
   foreach (TEntity type in path) ret += "." + type.Name;
   return ret;
}

//Put your line here:
var x = context.Employee.Include(typeof(Contact).GetRelation(
 typeof(SalesOrderHeader),
 typeof salesOrderDetail)));
```

I wish there would be a dynamic way of reflection...
Again, I am open minded, any suggestions would be blessed
thanks

Comment: That code won't work. You need to specify entity set names and property names, not type names. The code given will generate an incorrect argument in the call to Include

Comment: ... unless the property names and entity set names just happened to be identical to the type name.

Comment: Look at my new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683960/how-to-avoid-hardcoded-field-names-in-entity-framework/3433134#3433134